# Does the twilio_programmable_video flutter library support multi-user video calling

Tags: flutter, twilio

I want to use multi-user video call on twilio. Does this library support it?
In other words, does this library allow multiple users to join the same room?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is [an example with multiple participants](https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-chat-room-app-twilio-video-flutter-bloc)!

The 3rd party setup our Flutter library is supported by Twilio!It works just like any other Twilio Video product which supports multiple participants joining.